# How to find and replace blocks of text in Notepad++ or Brackets?

Tags: notepad++

This questions is so stupid it's ridiculous...but I couldn't find any  easy answer on Google...so here it is:

I have a list:

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

How can I replace

```
1
2
3
```

With:

```
4
5
6
```

So the result is:

```
4
5
6
a
b
c
```

Thanks

Comment: you can simply do a find and replace

Comment: Is it allways `1 2 3` or could it be any numbers, if so, what are the rules?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the following find and replacement in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
1(\r?\n)2\r?\n3
```

**Replace:**

```
4\15\16
```